# algorithm2e noend option produces wrong label

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I have a problem with the `algorithm2e` package. I want to reference the end of a block, e.g., a for-loop, in my text. Therefore, I place a label behind the closing bracket of the for statement. When I configure the package to produce an "end" line, the label correctly points to this line. But if I use the option "noend", the label points to the for statement instead of the last line of the for-loop.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[algo2e, noline]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm2e}  
    \For {...} { a = b\; }\label{x}  
\end{algorithm2e}
Reference: \ref{x}
\end{document}
```

The output would look somehow like this:

> 1 for ... do
>
> 2 a = b
>
> 3 end
>
> Reference: 3

When I reference label x in my text, I get a correct reference to line 3.

With the noend option for package `algorithm2e`, I get the following output:

> 1 for ... do
>
> 2 a = b
>
> Reference: 1

Label x now creates a reference to line 1 instead of line 2.

I guess it depends on how latex handles labels. I can fix it by putting the label behind the last line of my for-loop. But then the label would point to line 2 instead of 3 when I want to show "end" lines again.

Is there a possibility that always generates the correct reference independent of the option that I am using?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to reference. Can you please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg He wrote that the reference should point to line 2 instead of 1. Actually, I would expect that, too. Nonetheless it might be a feature of `algorithm2e`.

Comment: @egreg The previous example was working, but I tried to make it more precise. Hope it is clear now which reference is wrong with the "noend" option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most certainly triggered a bug in `algorithm2e`. While the manual is not very clear on that, I guess the behaviour of the `end` version is correct, and the label should refer to the last line of the block. The reason for this bug is that `\label` picks up `\@currentlabel`, but `algorithm2e` uses its own counter `AlgoLine`, and this is not pushed to `\@currentlabel` in all situations. The funny thing is that `algorithm2e` has special code for label handling when `hyperref` is loaded, and then everything works correct. So your recipe is:
1. Inform the maintainer of `algorithm2e` about this bug.
2a. Use the `hyperref` package.
2b. If you don't want to use `hyperref`, the following code defines a new labeling command, `\elabel`, which works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lined,linesnumbered,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \def\elabel#1{\label{#1}}%
}{%
  \def\elabel#1{\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{\theAlgoLine }{\thepage }}}\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SetAlgoShortEnd%
\begin{algorithm}%
\For {...} { a = b\; }                \label{ya}\elabel{ya2}
\end{algorithm}%
\textbackslash{}label gives \ref{ya}, \textbackslash{}elabel is \ref{ya2}%

\SetAlgoNoEnd%
\begin{algorithm}%
\For {...} { a = b }\label{xa}\elabel{xa2}
\end{algorithm}%
\textbackslash{}label is \ref{xa}, \textbackslash{}elabel is \ref{xa2}%
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: @Jubobs While I am fine with your edit, I am afraid the consensus on this site is [against it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/340/21591).

Comment: @mapf Ok. I wanted to correct a typo, but couldn't due to the 6-character limitation; therefore, I changed one more word. Sorry, and I totally understand.

Answer (score 3):

Without being too disruptive to the internal workings of the package I think the simplest thing to do is just make a label before or after the `}` depending on the `end` style.
You can define a `\label` variant that does nothing or makes a label depending on the option set.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[algo2e,noend,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\Aendlabel[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@optnoend}}{}{\label{#1}}}
\newcommand\Anoendlabel[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@optnoend}}{\label{#1}}{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm2e}  
    \For {...} { a = b\; \Anoendlabel{x}}\Aendlabel{x}
\end{algorithm2e}
Reference: \ref{x}
\end{document}
```

delete the `noend` option and you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\Aendlabel[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@optnoend}}{}{\label{#1}}}
\newcommand\Anoendlabel[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@optnoend}}{\label{#1}}{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm2e}  
    \For {...} { a = b\; \Anoendlabel{x}}\Aendlabel{x}
\end{algorithm2e}
Reference: \ref{x}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Your fix is a bit unwieldy but does the trick. I guess that's the best that can be done until the issue gets fixed in a subsequent release of `algorithm2e`. Unless someone comes up with something better soon, my bounty is yours.